# Conditional rendering on select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-operator

I am pretty new to the wonderful world of React.

I have two inputs passing data through from an API that renders a list of options. And I want to send the selected inputs from those options back to the parent in the input fields to display for another search.

I have tried passing state down to them and render them them optionally with both a ternary and an `if else` statement in the "SearchCityList" component in several ways but I either get both lists rendered and they would have to choose between one list that is doubled to put in each input field or it only puts the selected value in one input. Would appreciate any & all suggestions Thanks!

```
class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    showComponent: false,
    showComponent2: false,
  };


  // open/close control over SearchCity component box

  openSearch = () => {
    this.setState({ showComponent: true });
  };
  openSearch2 = () => {
    this.setState({ showComponent2: true });
  };
  closeSearch = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      showComponent: false,
      showComponent2: false
    });
  };

  // Passed down cb function to get selected city search in selectCity component

  GoingTo = (flights) => {
    this.setState({ GoingTo: [flights] });
  };
  LeavingFrom = (flights) => {
    this.setState({ LeavingFrom: [flights] });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-fields container">
          <div className="inputs">
            <h1>Search for a flight!</h1>
            <div className="depart">
              <input
                onClick={this.openSearch}
                className="flight-search"
                placeholder="Leaving From"
                value={this.state.LeavingFrom}
              ></input>
              <input type="date"></input>
            </div>
            <div className="Returning">
              <input
                onClick={this.openSearch2}
                className="flight-search"
                placeholder="Going To "
                value={this.state.GoingTo}
              ></input>
              <input type="date" placeholder="Returning"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button>Check Flights!</button>
        </form>

        {this.state.showComponent || this.state.showComponent2 ? (
          <SearchCity
          openSearch={this.openSearch}
          openSearch2={this.openSearch2}
            flightSearch={this.state.flightSearch}
            closeSearch={this.closeSearch}
            GoingTo={this.GoingTo}
            LeavingFrom={this.LeavingFrom}
            onSearchSubmission={this.onSearchSubmission}
            closeSearch={this.closeSearch}
          />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;


class SearchCity extends Component {
  state = {
    LeavingFrom: "",
    GoingTo: "",
    search: "",
    flightSearch: [],
  };

  // Search submission / api call
  onSearchSubmission = async (search) => {
    const response = await Axios.get(

      {
        headers: {
          "
          useQueryString: true,
        },
      }
    );
    // set New state with array of searched flight data sent to searchCity component

    const flightSearch = this.setState({ flightSearch: response.data.Places });
  };

  // Callback function to send search/input to parent "Form" component

  submitSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.onSearchSubmission(this.state.search);
  };

  //  closeSearch callback function sent from Form component to close pop up search box when X is pressed
  closeSearch = () => {
    this.props.closeSearch();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container search-list">
        <form onChange={this.submitSearch}>
          <i className="fas fa-times close-btn" onClick={this.closeSearch}></i>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ search: e.target.value })} //query-search api
            value={this.state.search}
            className="search-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search Locations"
          ></input>
          <div className="search-scroll">
            <SearchCityList
              openSearch={this.props.openSearch}
              openSearch2={this.props.openSearch2}
              LeavingFrom={this.props.LeavingFrom}
              GoingTo={this.props.GoingTo}
              flightSearch={this.state.flightSearch}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchCity;






function SearchCityList({ flightSearch, LeavingFrom, GoingTo }) {
  const renderList = flightSearch.map((flights) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectCityLeaving LeavingFrom={LeavingFrom} flights={flights} />
        <SelectCityGoing GoingTo={GoingTo} flights={flights} />
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div>{renderList}</div>;
}

export default SearchCityList;
```

Comment: Hello Josua, and welcome to StackOverflow community! It would be great is you read this first (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and don't forget to separate your question's text for part with problem/example/stage and so on)

Comment: Also I have found that you writing code via `class` component, instead of new (and much more easier to read`) React Hooks which was introduced since `React v16.8`  (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). It will be better (for you) if you'd using them, here is couple articles for you: (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, when dealing with state, make sure you initialize in the `constructor` and also ensure you bind your handlers to this component instance as `this` will refer to something else in the handlers if you don't and you won't be able to call `this.setState()`.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props); // important
  state = {
    // your state
  };
  // make sure to bind the handlers so `this` refers to the 
  // component like so
  this.openSearch = this.openSearch.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: as I understand from researching creating state in this manner state= { state : ''} is the equivalent to the constructor super method and is just a short hand version of writing it? I do not believe it is the cause of the issue as I had rewritten it with a constructor method as well but it did not help.

Comment: Well, that's not the way state works in class components; at least not the way the creators meant it to. You have to call `super(props)`. From the `docs`: `Class components should always call the base constructor with props.`. There is no short hand with state.